# Django - Database design for many to many relationship involving an attribute of the relationship

Tags: django, python-2.7, orm

I have two tables: **Pages** and **Questions**.
Since a question can be on multiple pages and a page has multiple questions this qualifies as a many to many relationship.
No problems so far (I also followed this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

let's say that the conceptual table structure looks like this:

**pages**:id_page(int)

**questions**:id_question(int), text(string)

**pageQuestions**:id_page(int), id_question(int), ordinal_number(int) - used to beak the many to many relationship

My problem is the "ordinal_number" field.This is supposed to order the questions on a page.
Since on every page a question can be on a different place, this field does not belong to the questions table.

Q: How can I declare this field in my django model since I'm not supposed to use the pageQuestions table ?

Comment: why are you not supposed to use pageQuestions ?

Comment: well, in the official example, the many to many relationship doesn't use a (visible) table, s I assumed that I should't add one  :| Am i wrong?

Comment: Well. you _can_ do it. It is called a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Very much used extensively

Comment: Ok, i'll read about that topic, but is this the best way to do it?
I mean it's pythonic/efficient/and so on ?

Comment: Pythonic? Yes, Django-ic ? Yes, Efficient? - It involves a join, so there is a overhead. And so on - yes yes and yes :P Jokes aside, it is the prefered method of doing it. It is simple, easy to comprehend and use.

Comment: Thank you :) I just found a pretty good discussion here: http://blog.hackedexistence.com/django-through-relationship-part-1-the-intermediary-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use an [intermediary table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) `pageQuestions` for what you are looking to achieve.

```
class Page:
   #attributes

class Questions:
   #attributes
   pages = models.ManyToManyField(through = 'PageQuestions', ...)

class PageQuestions:
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ordinal_number = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('page', 'question')) #optional
```

For the sake of completeness, Added the blog you found on [ManyToMany relationships](http://blog.hackedexistence.com/django-through-relationship-part-1-the-intermediary-model)